# ¿Como hago un Navigation schematic en un componente de Angular diferente de app.components.html?

Tags: angular, programación-funcional, router, framework, navigation

Estoy intentando hacer un Navigation schematic en Angular con Angular Material, cuando lo hago para el **app.component.html** funciona normal, pero quiero que los demas componentes que cree en adelante no lo tenga, para eso cree un componente **navegador.components** que es el unico que debe tener esa programación pero no funciona así:

**navegador.components**:

```
    <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/detallePedido" routerLinkActive="active">Pedidos</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/producto" routerLinkActive="active">Productos</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/usuario" routerLinkActive="active">Usuarios</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/categoria" routerLinkActive="active">Categorias</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/tienda" routerLinkActive="active">Tiendas</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>Ecomerce</span>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <router-outlet name="navegador"></router-outlet> **Es Aqui donde no se muestra dinámicamente la información**
        
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Luego cree configure las rutas en: **app-routing.module.ts**:

```
  import { NavegadorComponent } from './components/navegador/navegador.component';
  {
    path: 'navegador',
    component: NavegadorComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'navegador',
    outlet: 'navegador',
    component: NavegadorComponent
  }
```

**app.component.html**:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

No se si es la manera correcta de hacerlo, agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Quieres que el sidenav solamente aparezca al inicio? Es decir algo así como que solo aparezca en el Dashboard y que al abrir otra página ya no esté?

Comment: Exacto, mi aplicación tiene un Dashboard, pero también quiero abrir otras paginas y que no tengan el Dashcboard, sino el componente normal en blanco. ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso? Ten en cuneta que estoy utilizando Angular Material y su código del Navigator.